# setTimeout In HTML/CSS/JavaScript slideshow

Tags: javascript

I have a simple slider made with HTML/CSS/Javascript

My problem is that I don't know how to make a simple setTimeout. My idea is that the slides
must change when you click on any of the control dots ( that is already done by me and it works as expected). But a timer needs to work there too, so every 4 seconds this timer must change the active slide and if a control dot is clicked, the timer must resets and counts for another 4 seconds.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slides">
        <div class="intro-slide fade">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <p>
                text
            </p>
        </div>
        <!--slide-->
        <div class="intro-slide fade">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <p>
                text
            </p>
        </div>
        <!--slide-->
        <div class="intro-slide fade">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <p>
                text
            </p>
        </div>
        <!--slide-->
    </div>
    <!--slides-->
    <div class="control-dots">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
    <!--control-dots
            </div>
            <!--slideshow-container -->
```

SCSS

```
.slideshow-container {
    width: 570px;
    h2 {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 1.27;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-family: 'Raleway';
    }
    .control-dots {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .dot {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
        &:hover,
        &.active {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("intro-slide");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So cancel the timeout if it is running. The timeout returns the id of the timer. So you store that into a variable and cancel it.

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  n = n || 1
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

var activeTimer
function showSlides(n) {
    if (activeTimer) window.clearTimeout(activeTimer)
    // ...
    activeTimer = window.setTimeout(plusSlides, 4000);
}
```

Comment: setTimeout() doesn't change anything after 4 seconds... It doesn't call the showSlides function and display the next slide

Comment: I did not realize you were maintaining state with `n` being passed in, seems a bit weird, but you would need to change the timeout to pass n. I altered it to call plusSlides instead. A class would make this a lot cleaner.

Comment: Just found another way to do it, but with setInverval rather than setTimeout and your idea to clear it helped me, so I made it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: not sure why setInterval would make any difference. It would have the same issues as the original code. I alter the answer here to fix the issue you had with your timeout.